# PHP Sort function by date (JWPLAYER auto playlist script)

Tags: php, jwplayer

This will help anyone with JWPLAYER to make a playlist by scanning a folder and creating the correct XML file automatically.

I would like to add one function which I can not work out.

I would like to order the play list by name or date.

```
 $folder = opendir($path);
$start="<asx version='3.0'>n<title>Example ASX playlist</title>";
$Fnm = "./playlist.xml";
$inF = fopen($Fnm,"w");
fwrite($inF,$start."n");
while( $file = readdir($folder) ) {
     if (($file != '.')&&($file != '..')&&($file != 'index.htm')){
     $result="<entry>n<title>$file</title>n<ref href='$path2$file'/>n<param name='image' value='preview.jpg'/>n</entry>n";
         fwrite($inF,$result);
     }
}
fwrite($inF,"</asx>");
closedir($folder);
fclose($inF);
?>
```

Question:

I would like to add to the above code a sort function by date before creating the XML and list.

Thanks

Comment: You mean the date from when the file was created ?

Comment: When I upload the files to the video folder. It will use the date when uploaded to organize the playlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop the directory and get the date with filemtime and dump it in an array, here's a working script, you may change $path,$xmlfile or arsort() to sort() depanding on your needs ...

```
<?php

$xmlfile = "playlist.xml";
$path = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']). "/musicfolder";
$folder = scandir($path);
$files = array();
foreach($folder as $file){
    if($file == '.' OR $file == '..' OR $file == 'index.htm'){}else{
        $files[$file] = filemtime($path.'/'.$file);
    }
}
arsort($files);

//use asort to sort from old to new

$output="<asx version='3.0'>" . PHP_EOL . "<title>Example ASX playlist</title>";
foreach($files as $file => $date){
$output .= "<entry>" . PHP_EOL . "<title>$file</title>" . PHP_EOL . "<ref href='$path'/>" . PHP_EOL . "<param name='image' value='preview.jpg'/>" . PHP_EOL . "</entry>" . PHP_EOL;
}
$output .= "</asx>";
file_put_contents($xmlfile,$output);
?>
```

Comment: Great, testing it. Will get back to you... Thank you HamZa DzCyberDeV

Comment: Why not ? I did mention maybe you need to change the variables !

Comment: Ok perfect... I am trying it now! :)

Comment: Hi. This is the output of the XML `<entry>
<title>test.mp4</title>
<ref href=\'files\'/>
<param name=\'image\' value=\'preview.jpg\'/>
</entry>` but it should like this `<entry>
<title>test.mp4</title>
<ref href='http://xxx/player/files/test.mp4'/>
<param name='image' value='preview.jpg'/>
</entry>` I am not sure if I have missed something

Comment: `"<ref href=\'$path/$file'/>"` The code on the left shows up in the XML as <ref href=\'./files/xxx.mp4'/> but does not have the full URL.

Comment: - I think it is close, this is the message I get! `Warning: scandir(http://123.com/dev/player/files) [function.scandir]: failed to open dir:` BTW the XML is ordered in the right way. It is only this part now.

Comment: Got it working. `$xmlfile = "playlist.xml";
$path ="./files/";
$path2="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])."/files/";`

Comment: - This part make it arrange by date `$folder = scandir($path);
$files = array();
foreach($folder as $file){
    if($file == '.' OR $file == '..' OR $file == 'index.htm'){}else{
        $files[$file] = filemtime($path.'/'.$file);
    }
}
arsort($files);` what would have to look at to make it arrange by file name.

Comment: arsort() is to rearange the files by date, so if you remove it, then you would have files ordered by the system files (alphabeticaly) !

Answer (score 0):

Make an array with the files' name, datetime (using filemtime($file)) etc and sort accordingly.