# PHP sort funcation by name, change from filemtime

Tags: php, sorting

I have this piece of code which works, however I would like to change the function to "sort by name" opposed to "sort by date".

The code below is not mine (Please refer to [PHP Sort function by date (JWPLAYER auto playlist script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751794/php-sort-function-by-date-jwplayer-auto-playlist-script))

```
$folder = scandir($path);
$files = array();
foreach($folder as $file){
    if($file == '.' OR $file == '..' OR $file == 'index.htm'){}else{
        $files[$file] = filemtime($path.'/'.$file);
    }
}
arsort($files);
```

Thanks

To conclude.

With all the above information you can use JW Player to:

- To scan folder for video file and automatically create a playlist in XML
- Sort by date or sort by name

Thank you

Comment: Was not my code, please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751794/php-sort-function-by-date-jwplayer-auto-playlist-script but I am learning.

Comment: You posted the other question as well... Does that mean you're repeatedly posting someone else's code?

Comment: It is to improve the function as it is not the same as what was requested in the other post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$files` contains filename as a key then replace

```
arsort($files);
```

with

```
ksort($files);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$files[$file] = filemtime($path.'/'.$file);
```

with

```
$files[] = $path.'/'.$file;
```

And you might want to replace `arsort` with `asort`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ksort` instead of `arsort`

As [k(key)sort](http://php.net/manual/de/function.ksort.php) will sort your array by key rather than by value.